# How can I simulate cache using HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I want to calculate unique characters in a given string and cache them using collections, so that if the string is already present it won't calculate again. For this I have used `HashMap`, I have made the String as key and it's count as value. I have written the following code, but it won't add those key-value pairs in the map. How to resolve this problem?

```
class UniqueCharacters {

    public int uniqueCharacters(String s)
    {
        List<Character> list=new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++)
        {
            if(!(list.contains(s.charAt(i))))
            {
                list.add(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        for(Character c:list)
        {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        int count=list.size();
        maintainCache(s, count);

        System.out.println(count);
        return count;
    }

    public void maintainCache(String s, int count)
    {
        Map<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry: map.entrySet())
        {
            if(entry.getKey().equals(s))
            {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
                System.out.println("String was already there");
            }
            else
            {
                map.put(s, count);
                System.out.println("String added to the cache");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class UniqueCharactersTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        UniqueCharacters u=new UniqueCharacters();
        u.uniqueCharacters("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: See `map.get(..)`

Comment: declare the `map` globally

Comment: using a Map - or hasMap - is not just simulating a cache. It _is_ a cache.

Answer (score 1):

The `maintainCache` creates a new local variable `map` each time its called. If you want that map to retain its values between calls, you should extract it out of the method and keep it as a member.

Comment: It still doesn't work, can you please suggest if there are any other mistakes

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StringCacheTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringCache cache = new StringCache();

        System.out.println("Unique characters : " + cache.getUniqueCharactersCount("test"));
        System.out.println("Unique characters : " + cache.getUniqueCharactersCount("test2"));
        System.out.println("Unique characters : " + cache.getUniqueCharactersCount("test"));
    }

}

class StringCache {

    private Map<String, Long> cache;

    public StringCache(){
        this.cache = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Long getUniqueCharactersCount(String string){
        if(string == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("Null string");
        }
        if(cache.containsKey(string)){
            System.out.println("String " + string + " found in cache");
            return cache.get(string);
        } else {
            System.out.println("String " + string + " not found in cache");
            long uniqueCharactersCount = string
                    .chars()
                    .distinct()
                    .count();
            cache.put(string, uniqueCharactersCount);
            return uniqueCharactersCount;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HashMap is created newly everytime maintainCache is called. Please have the map as an property of UniqueCharacters class instead of local variable under method maintainCache